# Node-Red to parse sections of config file

Tags: parsing, node-red

I have a configuration file containing various parameters, including `yourdeviceid`, which has the value `"RFIN-MLD-EDGEBOX-001"`. I want to display this value in a text box on a dashboard. The file has this structure:

```
yourdeviceid = "RFIN-MLD-EDGEBOX-001";
debug = 1;
input0: {
   iomethod = "GPIO";
   input = 17;
   mode = "STROKE";
   debounce = 100;
   pullupdown = "OFF";
   action = "RUNNING,COUNTING";
};
```

How can I extract the value of `yourdeviceid` for display on the dashboard?

Comment: Given that it's not a standard format you are pretty much going to have to do it long hand. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76493318/edit) the question to show what you've tried and we'll help you fix it.